# How to call Javascript function on Url.Action on Kendo toolbar?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, toolbar

I have a kendo grid with a toolbar . I added a link to download from the toolbar and now the problem is i can't call Javascript function which goes to the controller with data.

How can i call java script function on Url.Action ?

**Toolbar**

```
 .ToolBar(toolBar => toolBar.Template("<a onclick='getData()' href ='" + Url.Action("", "", null, "https") + "?SeletectOrders=#= SeletectOrders#'" + ">Download Selected Orders</a>"))
```

If i put controller name and function, it pass an empty data to the controller and download empty file which shows at the bottom on browser. I am really not sure if am doing this correctly

**Javascript function which goes to the controller**

```
function getData(SeletectOrders)
{
$.ajax({

    url: '@Url.Action("myAction", "mycontroller")',
    type: "GET",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: "text",
    data: { SeletectOrders: SeletectOrders },
    traditional: true,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    complete: function (data) {
    },
    error: function () {
    }
})
}
```

**Controller**

```
   [HttpGet]
    public virtual ActionResult myAction(string[] SeletectOrders) 
    {


        List<string> ListPossDetails = new List<string>();
        if (SeletectOrders != null)
        {
            string[] OrderArray = SeletectOrders;
            foreach (var list in OrderArray)
            {
                ListPossDetails.Add(list);
            }
        }

        //download methods here

        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + possFilename);
        ListPossDetails = null;
        return File(fileBytes, type, possFilename);
    }
```

Comment: what kind of data are you trying to send?

Comment: From kendo grid columns, each row got checkbox and user can select row and am storing all the selected on an Array. now i want to hook my js function to come with the data on the url so that i can download the file

Comment: is SeletectOrders being passed with any parameters into the ajax call first?

Comment: data: { SeletectOrders: SeletectOrders } gets the data from,  var SeletectOrders = []; if that's what you asking

Comment: no i mean, when you get to the ajax call, are there objects there or no

Comment: Yes, there's data. I have just alert it again. So am not show if the constructing of my URL is the one preventing it to shows on browser when downloading cause i can pass the selected to action controller and click download which doesn't show on broswer, but it get stored on the local server.

Comment: i would try doing a POST and you're passing SeletectOrders but you don't have that parameter in your template